# error: The named parameter 'onSelectNotification' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-local-notification

i update flutter_local_notifications into 12.0.3 and show me this error:

error: The named parameter 'onSelectNotification' isn't defined. (undefined_named_parameter at [rosen] lib\services\notification\notification_service.dart:33)

and this is source of file:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:rosen/models/models.dart';
import 'package:rosen/screens/screens.dart' show LeaderBoardScreen;
import 'package:rosen/utils/logger.dart';

class NotificationService extends GetxService {
  final _notifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  @override
  void onInit() {
    _initNotifications();
    super.onInit();
  }

  Future<void> _initNotifications() async {
    const androidInitializationSettings =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/app_notification_icon');
    const iosInitializationSettings = DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: false,
      requestSoundPermission: false,
      requestBadgePermission: false,
    );
    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
            android: androidInitializationSettings,
            iOS: iosInitializationSettings);
     _notifications.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: (payload) {
      if (payload != null) {
        final QuizPaperModel quizPaperModel =
            QuizPaperModel.fromJson(json.decode(payload));
        Get.toNamed(LeaderBoardScreen.routeName, arguments: quizPaperModel);
        //MyApp.navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(LeaderBoardScreen.routeName, arguments:quizPaperModel);
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> showQuizCompletedNotification(
      {required int id,
      String? title,
      String? body,
      String? imageUrl,
      String? payload}) async {
    BigPictureStyleInformation? bigPictureStyleInformation;
    String? largeIconPath;

    if (imageUrl != null) {
      largeIconPath = await _downloadAndSaveFile(imageUrl, 'largeIcon');
      final String? bigPicturePath =
          await _downloadAndSaveFile(imageUrl, 'bigPicture');

      if (bigPicturePath != null) {
        bigPictureStyleInformation = BigPictureStyleInformation(
            FilePathAndroidBitmap(bigPicturePath),
            hideExpandedLargeIcon: true,
            contentTitle: '<b>$title</b>',
            htmlFormatContentTitle: true,
            summaryText: '<b>$body</b>',
            htmlFormatSummaryText: true);
      }
    }

    _notifications.show(
        id,
        title,
        body,
        NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails('quizcomplete', 'quizcomplete',
                channelDescription: 'Open leaderboard',
                importance: Importance.max,
                largeIcon: FilePathAndroidBitmap(largeIconPath!),
                styleInformation: bigPictureStyleInformation,
                priority: Priority.max),
            iOS: const DarwinNotificationDetails(
                presentAlert: true, presentBadge: true, presentSound: true)),
        payload: payload);
  }


  Future<String?> _downloadAndSaveFile(String url, String fileName) async {
    try {
      final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final String filePath = '${directory.path}/$fileName';
      final http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      final File file = File(filePath);
      await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
      return filePath;
    } catch (e) {
      AppLogger.e(e);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

i try to define parameter but failed because still learning flutter

how i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 15):

Since the version [`10.0.0`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/changelog#1000): `onSelectNotification` has been changed to `onDidReceiveNotificationResponse` as mentioned in the ChangeLog.md:

> `onDidReceiveNotificationResponse`: invoked only when the app is running. This works for when a user has selected a notification or notification action. This replaces the `onSelectNotification` callback that existed before.

Comment: i replace it but still have alot of error .. can you help me to migrate into new version .. the code up there in main topic if you want to have look and help ..

Answer (score 1):

you have to use onDidReceiveNotificationResponse